# Wrong settings broke my site

Tags: cdn

I installed the [CDN](https://www.drupal.org/project/cdn) module. In the UI, I set a wrong CDN path.

Now the site is broken and I cannot disable the module from the UI. I have administration access to the server, but I can't figure out how to disable the module. There is a cdn.settings.yml file, but the option isn't there.

I can't find any documentation for the module. Can you please help me?

Comment: I fixed removing completely the two addons with:

drush pm:uninstall cdn_ui

drush pm:uninstall cdn